# Unable to install npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I have to install npm package hence used command - `npm install -g <package-name>` but it resulted into write access error so I changed permissions as follows with refernce to https://flaviocopes.com/npm-fix-missing-write-access-error/

```
sudo chown -R $USER /opt/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/
```

and tried again but if failed again -

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js
npm ERR! dest /opt/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64/bin/r.js
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js' -> '/opt/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64/bin/r.js'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js' -> '/opt/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64/bin/r.js']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js' -> '/opt/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64/bin/r.js'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!      path: '../lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js',
npm ERR!      dest: '/opt/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64/bin/r.js' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink \'../lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js\' -> \'/opt/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64/bin/r.js\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../lib/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/opt/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64/bin/r.js' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

also when I run command with `sudo`, it gives `npm not found`. Please guide what is wrong here.

Comment: By default, you don't have permission to write data to the folder `/opt`. Right click on that folder and select `Get info`, scroll down to the bottom and check `Sharing and Permissons`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need read write permissions to /opt/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64/ as it creates a symlink there for you.
you can also check the destination in error it clearly says you don't have permission there.

Comment: Thanks this worked as you said I should have given permission till `sudo chown -R $USER /opt/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64/`